# TFS Task plugin upload exception and create warning on console

Tags: azure-devops, tfsbuild, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Getting exception and warning while uploading and package extension of Build Task.

I make a build task plugin i use below manifest file

```
{
 "id": "sample-custom-build-task",
 "type": "ms.vss-distributed-task.task",
 "description": "Adds sample type Build Task",
 "targets": [
               "ms.vss-distributed-task.tasks"
           ],
 "properties": {
               "name": "buildtask"
               }
}
```

Buildtask is a folder in home directory that contains node_modules,task.json,tsconfig,package.json and task image file.

tsConfig.json is look like this.

```
{
  "compilerOptions":  
   {
     "target": "es6",                          
     "module": "commonjs",                     
     "lib": ["es2015"],                       
     "allowJs": true,                       
     "checkJs": true,                       
     "sourceMap": true,                     
     "removeComments": true,                
     "strict": true,                         
     "noImplicitAny": false,                 
     "moduleResolution": "node",            
     "typeRoots": ["node_modules/typings"], 
     "types": ["node"]                      
  },
 "exclude": [
           "**/node_modules/*",
           "/NodeExecutor.ts"
  ],
  "enableAutoDiscovery":true
 }
```

Whenever i package my plugin there is some warning on console.
Refer image

[image: tfx extension create warning on console]

and upload an extension show this error
[image: TFS extension Upload Warning]

Strange, for me, in past i make build task plugin but no error and warning whenever i add node_modules in my package it gave me error.

What i going to wrong, i add whole build task folder in my manifest file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the detail requirement you want to achieve in that build task? What's the version of your TFS? Can you share it on the OneDrive?

Comment: Version of TFS is 2017, when i use this with VSTS thats work fine.

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue with TFS 2017.1 and TFS 2017.3. (node_modules contains @types/node package and include in build task) What's the detail version of TFS 2017?

Comment: I am using TFS2017 update 2, I use this link 'https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-task-lib/blob/master/node/docs/stepbystep.md' for tutorial, and follow each step except this "$ cat .gitignore
node_modules" i could not understand this step, and issue is reproducible

Comment: Can you share your project on the OneDrive?

Comment: Here is dropbox link, which contains rar file for sample which reproduce this issue "https://www.dropbox.com/s/uu3sfwhy0plqyee/VSTS_Task_Sample.rar?dl=1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `"addressable": true` code for BuildTask:

```
"files": [
    {
      "path": "logo.png",
      "addressable": true
    },
    {
      "path": "BuildTask"
    }
  ]
```

Also, the BuildTask folder should contains task.json file.

Comment: What do you mean by the BuildTask folder should contains task.json file? When i remove addressable and upload new extension, it give me an error that task.json not found

Comment: For build task extension, there is the task.json file in related build/release task folder, check this article:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/develop/add-build-task

Comment: Got it what you want to say, can you tell me one thing more that if i unpack my extension i can see typescript file, how can i avoid this for pacaging.

Comment: Remove typescript file from task folder, don't need to include it in that folder.